# How to add overflow y to specific div only

Tags: css, scroll

I have a sidebar where a list of the recipe is available but the list will be long enough that the user will need to scroll down. Now what I want to achieve is to add vertical scroll only to that sidebar not to the whole page. So when a user scrolls down only that sidebar scrolls, not the whole page.

I tried to disabled overflow-y (hidden) of the whole page and only added overflow-y to scroll to that sidebar but when I increase the list, it doesn't work. If I remove overflow-y (hidden) from HTML and body tag and try again, I get a scroll bar to the whole page.

```
.recipe-list {
        list-style-type: none;
        width: 100%;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        flex-direction: column;
        align-items: center;
        margin: 1rem 0;
        overflow-y: scroll;
    }
```

NOTE: I am using CSS GRIDs.

Here is my result

Normal : 
[image: Normal]

Increasing List

[image: Adding Content]

Comment: apply max-height..

Comment: @KamaleshM.Talaviya , Thank you It Worked.

Comment: @vipul , yes it is

Answer (score 0):

As Kamalesh M. Talaviya mentioned, u should apply max-height.
Also make sure that you are using overflow-y: auto. This will only show the scrollbar when it is needed. (So u won't see the ugly scrollbar if there is no need to.)

Answer (score 0):

To make overflow work properly, you need to adjust height to expand to max container height. I assume that at beginning you want to have 100% parent height, then if more elements are added, scroll should be available.

```css
.container {
  background: green; 
  height: 300px;
  width: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
}

.left, .right {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100%;
}
.left {
  width: 40%;
  background: lightgreen;
}

.list-wrapper {
  max-height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="left list-wrapper">
    <ul>
      <li class="some element">Something</li>
      <li class="some element">Something</li>
      <li class="some element">Something</li>
      <li class="some element">Something</li>
      <li class="some element">Something</li>
      <li class="some element">Something</li>
      <li class="some element">Something</li>
      <li class="some element">Something</li>
      <li class="some element">Something</li>
      <li class="some element">Something</li>
      <li class="some element">Something</li>
      <li class="some element">Something</li>
      <li class="some element">Something</li>
      <li class="some element">Something</li>
      <li class="some element">Something</li>
      <li class="some element">Something</li>
      <li class="some element">Something</li>
      <li class="some element">Something</li>
      <li class="some element">Something</li>
      <li class="some element">Something</li>
      <li class="some element">Something</li>
      <li class="some element">Something</li>
      <li class="some element">Something</li>
      <li class="some element">Something</li>
      <li class="some element">Something</li>
      <li class="some element">Something</li>
      <li class="some element">Something</li>
      <li class="some element">Something</li>
      <li class="some element">Something</li>
      <li class="some element">Something</li>
      <li class="some element">Something</li>
      <li class="some element">Something</li>
    <ul>
  </div>
  <div class="right">
  <div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply give your recipes list a height and a scrollable overflow-y:

```css
ul {
  background: #eee;
  height: 300px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  width: 200px;
}

li {
  background: #ccc;
  line-height: 50px;
  margin: 20px 0;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <ul>
    <li>Lorem Ipsum</li>
    <li>Lorem Ipsum</li>
    <li>Lorem Ipsum</li>
    <li>Lorem Ipsum</li>
    <li>Lorem Ipsum</li>
    <li>Lorem Ipsum</li>
    <li>Lorem Ipsum</li>
    <li>Lorem Ipsum</li>
  </ul>
</body>
```

Hope this works for you!